# Texstudio structure view test failed!

Tags: texstudio

After installing TexStudio I get the following error. It occurs with TexStudio 2.3 (Ubuntu 13.04 repo) as well as with 2.5.2 (ppa:blahota/texstudio). Before filing a TexStudio Bug report I wanted to ask, whether someone can see whether it is TexStudio related or something else?

```
********* Start testing of StructureViewTest *********
Config: Using QTest library 4.8.4, Qt 4.8.4
PASS   : StructureViewTest::initTestCase()
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(add Label) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(add Label2) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(add Label3) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change Label) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change Label2) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change Label3) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcst3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcst3 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(remove line) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test2 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test4 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(remove lines2) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(add section) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(add section2) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change section) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change section2) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:3 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:3 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change section3) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:4 IND:2
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:4 IND:2
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
FAIL!  : StructureViewTest::script(change section4) Compared values are not the same
   Actual (res1.join("##")): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:?TIQUETTES LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Expected (expectedStructure): Root: LVL:0 IND:0##Overview:LABELS LVL:0 IND:1##Label:test LVL:0 IND:2##Label:test5 LVL:0 IND:2##Label:tabcest6 LVL:0 IND:2##Section:sec:test LVL:2 IND:1##Section:sabcec:test LVL:2 IND:1
   Loc: [tests/structureview_t.cpp(215)]
RESULT : StructureViewTest::benchmark():"single line text":
     0.10 msecs per iteration (total: 52, iterations: 512)
RESULT : StructureViewTest::benchmark():"labels1":
     0.18 msecs per iteration (total: 94, iterations: 512)
RESULT : StructureViewTest::benchmark():"labels2":
     0.15 msecs per iteration (total: 79, iterations: 512)
RESULT : StructureViewTest::benchmark():"labels3":
     0.14 msecs per iteration (total: 74, iterations: 512)
RESULT : StructureViewTest::benchmark():"sections":
     0.10 msecs per iteration (total: 53, iterations: 512)
RESULT : StructureViewTest::benchmark():"sections with many children":
     0.15 msecs per iteration (total: 80, iterations: 512)
PASS   : StructureViewTest::benchmark()
PASS   : StructureViewTest::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 14 failed, 0 skipped
********* Finished testing of StructureViewTest *********
```

Comment: TeXstudio 2.5.2 and 2.6 for Windows work without a problem. This really looks more like a bug.

Comment: TeXstudio 2.6? Where did you get that from? We haven't released this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Ubuntu (and Debian) have the policy to build debug versions and strip the debug symbols for packages. In the case of TXS the debug version additionally runs a set of tests which you are encountering here.

We already have implemented a workaround for this (see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texstudio/+bug/1154261). So you can assume this to be fixed in a future release. Alternatively, if you want to have this fixed directly, you may compile from source using the SVN version and the BUILD.sh script.